# Lucene Fast Vector Highlightor fragments

Tags: lucene, lucene-highlighter

Im new to Lucene. Is there a way to get the Lucene FVH to return fragments/snippets centered around the search query instead of approximately starting with the search query? Also, Is there a way to tell the FVH fragmenter to fragment only at the newline char?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sujit Pal has a description of how to create your own fragments builder on his Salmon Run blog: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/05/customizing-lucenes-fast-vector.html

Also, Grant Ingersoll has a post at the Lucid blog about using a TermVectorMapper to construct a window around the terms so that you can pull N preceding and subsequent terms: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/05/26/accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pure lucene way to do this, apart from making your own frag builder AFAIK. However, you can provide **Solr** with a regex indicating how you want fragments to look. See [the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters).